# Script completes successfully in Windows 7, but not Win 8.1

Tags: windows, sharepoint, vbscript, windows-7, windows-8.1

I have a VBScript that I use to automatically renew the login to a Microsoft SharePoint site (Windows Task Scheduler runs the script on a nightly basis).  I do this because I have a network drive mapped to the SharePoint, and the drive loses connection if the site is not visited often enough. The script successfully does the following in Windows 7:

1. Opens Internet Explorer
2. Navigates to Sharepoint site
3. Enters and Submits Login Credentials
4. Waits 30 seconds
5. Closes SharePoint IE window.

However, in Windows 8.1, the script seems to stop after submitting the credentials, as the window remains open indefinitely.  I'm hoping some of the more experienced users here can help me alter the script to avoid this inconsistency.

Here is the code:

```
On Error Resume Next

Const PAGE_LOADED = 4

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Call objIE.Navigate("https://XXXXXX-my.sharepoint.com")
objIE.Visible = True

Do Until objIE.ReadyState = PAGE_LOADED : Call WScript.Sleep(100) : Loop

objIE.Document.all.login.Value = "XXXXXXXX"
objIE.Document.all.Passwd.Value = "XXXXXXXX"

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    msgbox "Error: " & err.Description

    For Each Button In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
        If InStr(Button.getAttribute("onclick"), "Sign In()") Then
            Button.Click()
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End If

Call objIE.Document.all.credentials.submit

WScript.Sleep 30000
Set sa = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set windows = sa.Windows()

For Each window In sa.windows
    If left(window.LocationUrl, 5) <> "file:" Then
        ' logic for selecting windows goes here
        If InStr(window.locationUrl,"sharepoint") Then window.Quit()
        If UCase(window.locationUrl) = UCase("about:tabs") Then window.Quit()
    End If
Next

Set objIE = Nothing
```

Comment: Does it work when you run it manually (not via Task Scheduler)? Do you get an error if you remove `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: I get the same result when running manually.  The only difference when running with task scheduler is that I get a pop-up asking me which browser I want to use.  Running manually just opens IE as intended.  Removing the `On Error Resume Next` produces an error code 80010108: "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients"  on the line `Do Until objIE.ReadyState = PAGE_LOADED : Call WScript.Sleep(100) : Loop`